# While loops in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

Is it possible to have `while` loops in TikZ, or some equivalent loop which only terminates after a certain condition?

Comment: It's possible to use pgffor package outside of TikZ. The loops are not a real part of TikZ also you can use what you want to make loop, while loop etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can combine the loop `\foreach` with the provided command `\breakforeach`. The following example is copied from the manual.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
 \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
   {
    \fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse (3pt and 6pt);
    \ifnum \x<\y
     \breakforeach
    \fi
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: However, the current execution of the <commands> is continued normally, so it is probably best to use this command only at the end of a \foreach command.

Answer (score 8):

Update `\whiledo` is defined in the package `ifthen` and not `calc`

TikZ is based on TeX also you can build a while loop with TeX but it's also possible to use different packages like `ifthen`. With `ifthen`  you can use the macro `\whiledo` and macros from TikZ.

Comment: You are right, this a mistake. I would like to say `ifthen`. Sorry